# ElasticSearch plugins: "Failed to resolve config path" error

Tags: java, debian, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I install elasticsearch 1.7.3 on debian jessie. It uses default config files and works normally. But when i call `sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin` it returns an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.env.FailedToResolveConfigException: Failed to resolve config path ["/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml"], tried file path ["/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml"], path file ["/usr/share/elasticsearch/config"/"/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml"], and classpath
        at org.elasticsearch.env.Environment.resolveConfig(Environment.java:291)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:95)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginManager.main(PluginManager.java:396)
```

File `/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml` is exists and i can open him in nano.

There is /etc/default/elasticsearch file:

```
# Start Elasticsearch automatically
START_DAEMON=true

# Run Elasticsearch as this user ID and group ID
#ES_USER=elasticsearch
#ES_GROUP=elasticsearch

# Heap Size (defaults to 256m min, 1g max)
#ES_HEAP_SIZE=2g

# Heap new generation
#ES_HEAP_NEWSIZE=

# max direct memory
#ES_DIRECT_SIZE=

# Maximum number of open files, defaults to 65535.
#MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535

# Maximum locked memory size. Set to "unlimited" if you use the
# bootstrap.mlockall option in elasticsearch.yml. You must also set
# ES_HEAP_SIZE.
#MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited

# Maximum number of VMA (Virtual Memory Areas) a process can own
#MAX_MAP_COUNT=262144

# Elasticsearch log directory
#LOG_DIR=/var/log/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch data directory
#DATA_DIR=/var/lib/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch work directory
#WORK_DIR=/tmp/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch configuration directory
#CONF_DIR=/etc/elasticsearch

# Elasticsearch configuration file (elasticsearch.yml)
#CONF_FILE=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

# Additional Java OPTS
#ES_JAVA_OPTS=

# Configure restart on package upgrade (true, every other setting will lead to not restarting)
#RESTART_ON_UPGRADE=true
```

There are no records in `/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log` and `/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.error` files.

Does anybody know why is can fail?

Comment: Have you tried to first cd into `/usr/share/elasticsearch` and then calling `bin/plugin`?

Comment: @Val Yes. It was same result.

Comment: I have the same problem...

Comment: @ fccoelho I resolved this problem by hack. See my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not resolve of question. But i resolved my problem.

Script in `/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin` generate bash-command and run it. I edited this file. It printed this command by `echo` instead running it. I copied this command and ran it from bush terminal. And it ran correctly.

I don't know why but it work. May be it will be helpful for someone.

Comment: Some issue with the classpath, but this accepted answer works. Thank you!

Comment: can you post exactly what you did? I mean the commands themselves.

Comment: edit ```/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin```, on the last line change ```exec``` to ```echo```.

Comment: You can add ` | /bin/bash` to the end if you don't want to copy/paste a command to run it: this pipes the command to bash.

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck with the same problem, too -- 2016, September. Turned out, **this problem occurs with an old version of elastic search** (i.e. 1.7.3) which is in the repos for **Ubuntu**. Use the current one (which is recommended anyway) and you should not get this error.

To install the current one (writing this, it is version 2.4) follow [these steps](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-repositories.html):

```
wget -qO - https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb https://packages.elastic.co/elasticsearch/2.x/debian stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elasticsearch-2.x.list

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 2):

These changes fixed the issue for me:

```
--- /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/plugin 2015-12-24 05:14:52.000000000 +0000
+++ /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/pluginfix  2018-04-21 22:54:49.547134959 +0000
@@ -79,7 +79,7 @@
       properties="$properties \"$var\"=\"$1\""
       ;;
     *)
-      args="$args \"$1\""
+      args="$args $1"
   esac
   shift
 done
@@ -90,7 +90,7 @@
     *-Des.default.path.conf=*|*-Des.path.conf=*)
     ;;
     *)
-      properties="$properties -Des.default.path.conf=\"$CONF_DIR\""
+      properties="$properties -Des.default.path.conf=$CONF_DIR"
     ;;
   esac
 fi
@@ -100,11 +100,11 @@
     *-Des.default.config=*|*-Des.config=*)
     ;;
     *)
-      properties="$properties -Des.default.config=\"$CONF_FILE\""
+      properties="$properties -Des.default.config=$CONF_FILE"
     ;;
   esac
 fi

 export HOSTNAME=`hostname -s`

-exec "$JAVA" $JAVA_OPTS $ES_JAVA_OPTS -Xmx64m -Xms16m -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=\""$ES_HOME"\" $properties -cp \""$ES_CLASSPATH"\" org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginManager $args
+exec "$JAVA" $JAVA_OPTS $ES_JAVA_OPTS -Xmx64m -Xms16m -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home="$ES_HOME" $properties -cp "$ES_CLASSPATH" org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginManager $args
```

The workaround posted by Pikaev Viktor applies essentially the same fix. Through the action of copy-pasting the command that would be executed by the script, one level of pairs of quotes get removed by the shell.

This bug has also been reported to <del>Ubuntu</del> Debian (see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=807596) but has been marked as won't fix because:

> ... the package elasticsearch has just been removed from the Debian archive unstable ...

as of March 11, 2018.

Answer (score 0):

Try this step [work for my]:
1. run *elasticsearch* 
2. check *ps aux | grep elast*
3. you will get shomething like 
`elastic+ 12723  4.3 25.7 4623016 261176 ?      Sl   13:27   0:22 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Delasticsearch -Des.pidfile=/var/run/elasticsearch.pid -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp :/usr/share/java/lucene-replicator-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-facet-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-morfologik-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-kuromoji-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-join-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-suggest-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/log4j-1.2-1.2.17.jar:/usr/share/java/jts.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-expressions-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/spatial4j-0.4.1.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-highlighter-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/sigar.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-memory-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-icu-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-misc-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-smartcn-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-benchmark-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-phonetic-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-uima-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-sandbox-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-classification-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/elasticsearch-1.7.3.jar:/usr/share/java/groovy-all-2.x.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-test-framework-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-codecs-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-queryparser-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar:/usr/share/java/jna.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-spatial-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-queries-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-stempel-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-demo-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-grouping-4.10.4.jar: -Des.default.config=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml -Des.default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.work=/tmp/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch`
4. now use
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Delasticsearch -Des.pidfile=/var/run/elasticsearch.pid -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp :/usr/share/java/lucene-replicator-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-facet-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-morfologik-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-kuromoji-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-join-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-suggest-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-core-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/log4j-1.2-1.2.17.jar:/usr/share/java/jts.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-expressions-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/spatial4j-0.4.1.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-highlighter-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/sigar.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-memory-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-icu-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-misc-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-smartcn-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-benchmark-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-phonetic-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-uima-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-sandbox-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-classification-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/elasticsearch-1.7.3.jar:/usr/share/java/groovy-all-2.x.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-test-framework-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-codecs-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-queryparser-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar:/usr/share/java/jna.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-spatial-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-queries-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-stempel-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-analyzers-common-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-demo-4.10.4.jar:/usr/share/java/lucene-grouping-4.10.4.jar: -Des.default.config=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml -Des.default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.work=/tmp/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch` 
as command and do (for example):
*$command org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginManager -i elasticsearch/elasticsearch-analysis-stempel* 
or check for help *$command org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginManager -h*